# Get total of field of Mongodb collection in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I can find the answer (think?) for plain Mongodb querying, but nothing for Java for this particular use case...

I have a collection that is typed to the following object:

```java
public class TestObj {
    ObjectId id;
    long value = 0;
    // etc
}
```

I would like the sum of the `value` field across all objects held in the collection. How can I do this?

My current hangup is no matter wat I do, the aggregate method from the collection returns the type `TestObj`, and not a more generic object with the answer I seek. I have tried `project`, but didn't seem to have any effect.

Current code:

```java
    public long getTotalValue(){
        Object returned = this.getCollection().aggregate(
            List.of(
                Aggregates.group(null, Accumulators.sum("$value", 1))
            )
        );
        //TODO:: get sum
        return 0L;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count how many collections have the **value** field you can use count in aggregation.

But if you want the sum of the values that the **value** field has in your collections you can calculate it like this with mongoDb aggregation

```
Arrays.asList(new Document("$group", 
   new Document("_id", 
   new BsonNull())
        .append("value", 
   new Document("$sum", "$value"))))
```

value is the name of your field in the collection.

Full example:

```java
Document returned = this.getCollection().aggregate(
    List.of(new Document(
        "$group",
        new Document(
            "_id",
            new BsonNull()
        )
            .append(
                "value",
                new Document("$sum", "$numExpired")
            )
    )),
    Document.class
).first();
        
return returned.getLong("value");
```

Comment: Thanks! This might be the answer, but the aggregate still wants to return with type `TestObj`, rather than a generic Document. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out by setting the second parameter of the `aggregate()` method to `Document.class`